# Chrome extension - Get HTML of current tab for every request

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm writing an extension that should get the HTML source of the current tab that I'm in and store it in a variable.

Here is my code so far:

```
chrome.webRequest.onCompleted.addListener(function(details) { 
  chrome.tabs.query({currentWindow: true, active: true},function(tabarray){
    var mkup = document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].outerHTML;
  });
},{urls:["<all_urls>"]});
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What's the specific question?

Comment: The question im trying to answer is : how do I get the html of the current tab everytime a request completes?

Comment: One more question: Are you really trying to get the HTML after every single request, or do you simply want to get the HTML for new pages/tabs that the user opens?

Comment: Thats correct, I am trying to get the html after every single request. Is this possible?